# R - Error computing interpolated mean by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, median

I am trying to compute the interpolated median by group for a number of variables.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  id            eu_image eu_insurance eurobonds free_movement_welfare eu_cn_solidarity country_code country_party_mass
  <chr>            <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>                 <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl+lbl>    <chr>             
1 CAWI200000100        4            4         4                     3                3 2            germany_7         
2 CAWI300000784        2            2         1                     1                1 3            italy_9           
3 CAWI100000787        3            3         2                     2                3 1            france_13         
4 CAWI500000081        3            2         2                     1                3 5            spain_2           
5 CATI500000067        4            3         2                     2                6 5            spain_3           
6 CAWI100000398        2            4         4                     2                5 1            france_2
```

When I run the following code to compute the interpolated mean by the grouping variable *country_party_mass*:

```
party_median <- newdata %>%
    group_by(country_party_mass) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_at(c(   "eu_image", 
                      "eu_cn_solidarity", 
                      "eurobonds", 
                      "free_movement_welfare", 
                      "eu_insurance"), 
    funs(interp.median(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

**I get the following error**:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>         Column `eu_cn_solidarity` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0

I have checked previous questions on similar issues, but I could not find a viable solution.

Comment: All `eu_cn_solidarity` is NA for some `country_party_mass`. e.g. `mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4,'gear']<-NA;mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_at(vars(c('hp','gear')),~interp.median(.,na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you, this is the actual problem. Do you know if there is a way to keep the group name with NA instead of the median for those groups with not enough observations?

Comment: I think Cettt's answer can do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on A. Suliman's comment:
you can add an `ifelse` function to check if all entries are `NA`:

```
party_median <- newdata %>%
    group_by(country_party_mass) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_at(vars(c("eu_image", 
                      "eu_cn_solidarity", 
                      "eurobonds", 
                      "free_movement_welfare", 
                      "eu_insurance")), 
    ~ifelse(all(is.na(.)), NA_real_, interp.median(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Note that the `funs` function is now soft deprecated (as of dplyr 0.8.0.1) so I use the "~" notation instead. Also I use the `vars` function to select variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.